# Hosted wiki using StackOverflow-like editing tools?

Tags: wiki, markdown, wmd

We're starting developer documentation for one of our projects, and I'd like to set it up as a hosted wiki.

There will be lots of code samples, and the WMD/Prettify combination used here on StackOverflow is the simplest way I've seen to enter structured text (with headings, etc.) combined with automatically formatted code blocks.

Does anyone know of an existing hosted wiki service that uses this editing toolset, so we don't have to write our own (at least not right away)?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for understanding SO's limitations.  When it first launched I saw so many requests for hosted/local versions people could use internally, but the voting and competitive features just wouldn't translate well to an internal shop.  As a docs tool, though, the editing features are pretty nice.

Comment: Joel: for real? the dude just wants a wiki!

Comment: What this question isn't closed yet?

Comment: No, he want's a wiki + Markdown

Comment: Just curious about the two "close" votes - why? It's not precisely a programming question, but it is a question about how to avoid programming, so I think it's appropriate.

Comment: Joel: Yikes Markdown! Any wiki worth its salt can handle multiple markup formats eg markdown. This is not exactly a feature.

Comment: See comment below - I'm looking for a hosted service on a subscription model. I'm not looking to customize and run a wiki on my own servers for now.

Answer (score 1):

Many wiki engines are open source

Why not grab your favourite and add in the WMD editor?

Screwturn.eu is a nice C# wiki with a great extensibility model, and a great markup pipeline what should be simpl-ish to upgrade to WMD

Download v3 beta and look at /core/Formatter.cs and /core/FormattingPipeline.cs for the REGEX's to compose pages from WMD markdown

And /WebApplication/Editor.ascx for the editor custom control, which you can plug in WMD with some LH-RH code

Comment: Thanks- I'm looking for a hosted service on a subscription model. I'm not looking to customize and run a wiki on my own servers for now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mindtouch's DekiWiki](http://www.mindtouch.com/).  They use [fckeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/demo), I believe, which is pretty user friendly.  There is a free hosted version (with limited extension features), and you can pay for very powerful version.

We use it for documentation internally and it is excellent.